# Execute another program in multi-threaded program

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Just wondering how if it's possible to execute another program in a thread and send information to/get information from it. Essentially the same concept as with a child process and using pipes to communicate - however I don't want to use fork.

I can't seem to find whether it's possible to do this, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not possible, at least as you have described it.  If you tell us why you're trying to do this, perhaps we can help you come up with a solution.

Comment: You can use `popen()` to exedcute a process asynchronously. However you can only capture either the stdin or stdout of the started process. It still uses `fork()` internally, but in Linux/Unix it's the only way of starting a new process. There are probably some higher level libraries that do everything for you (pipe/fork/dup/exec) if you don't want to code it manually.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the `exec` family of functions to load another executable file within a thread; the `exec` functions replace the entire process with the process started from the executable.  Thus `fork()` is necessary if you want your original process to keep running.

In theory you could replicate most of the behaviour of the `exec` system call in userspace, and run an executable within a thread - but as the thread would share the open file table, signal handlers and so on with the rest of the process, it would likely destructively interfere with the main process.  It would also be a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using fork (directly or indirectly), then it's not really another process.  Of course, you can communicate between threads within a process.  That's essential to most multithreading.